# Probability generating function question help

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have an exercise which is regarding conditional pgfs. I know that: $PGF(z) = E[z^Y] = E[E[z^Y|X]]$.

But I'm not sure how to find $E[z^Y|X]$, because I'm confused about what exactly $z^Y$ is. Say $X$ is exponentially distributed with rate 1 and $Y|X=x$ is Poisson distributed. How would I find $E[z^Y|X]$ and then the PGF?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y|X=x$ is non-negative discrete then $$E[z^Y|X=x]=\sum_{y=0}^\infty  z^y P(Y=y|X=x)$$ which if $Y|X=x$ is Poisson distributed with mean and variance $X=x$ might be $e^{x(z-1)}$. Then if $X$ is non-negative continuous with density $p(x)$ you have $$E[E[z^Y|X]] = \int_{x=0}^\infty  E[z^Y|X=x] \;p(x)\; dx$$ which if $X$ has an exponential distribution with rate $1$ might be $\frac{1}{2-z}$, though I have not checked and you should do the summation and integration yourself.

Comment: That's what I got in the end. Thanks, this really helped!